# Difference caused by placement of PRIOR statement in an Oracle hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

Seems you can do both the following in Oracle when working with Connect By.

```
 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE 
    parent_id = PRIOR child_r_object_id

 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR 
    parent_id = child_r_object_id
```

What is the difference, most examples on line tend to use the second syntax, but both execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you define to build the hierarchy from top-to-down or from down-to-top.

Have a look at this examples to see the difference:

```
WITH t(person, parent_id, ID) AS (
    SELECT 'Grandma', NULL, 1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mother', 1, 10 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Daughter', 10, 100 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Son', 10, 101 FROM dual)
SELECT person AS leaf_person, CONNECT_BY_ROOT(person) AS top_person, 
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(person, '->'), 'down' AS direction
FROM t
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY parent_id = PRIOR ID
UNION ALL
SELECT person as leaf_person, CONNECT_BY_ROOT(person) as top_person, 
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(person, '->'), 'up' AS direction
FROM t
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH ID IN (100,101)
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = ID;


+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|LEAF_PERSON|TOP_PERSON|SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(PERSON,'->')|DIRECTION|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Daughter   |Grandma   |->Grandma->Mother->Daughter     |down     |
|Son        |Grandma   |->Grandma->Mother->Son          |down     |
|Grandma    |Daughter  |->Daughter->Mother->Grandma     |up       |
|Grandma    |Son       |->Son->Mother->Grandma          |up       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Typically you have just one root (i.e. `parent_id IS NULL`) or at least determined root elements, thus most examples use the "top-to-down" direction.

Comment: Thanks, could you add an example to show how you would add a column showing the ID of the root node, i.e. for all rows with GRANDMA as the root, there should be a column stating an ID of 1.  You could then use this to join the employee table to this query on the ID to see all Grandmas descendants.  i.e. an example of CONNECT_BY_ROOT

Comment: I am assuming we can have multiple root nodes, in our table we have documents representing a virtual document structure (like a folder structure).  There are many root level folders/documents at the same level

Comment: Yes, you may have several root elements. When you work with Foreign-Key constraints then you are forced to start inserting the root elements. However, once the data is inserted you can connect in either direction.

Comment: In our table, the root node is joined to itself - its the virtual document structure data model in document management system.  We need to deal with such cases and manually remove this bogus relationship, which seesm to be used as a way to identify the root document to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The "prior" keyword what field is for parent record.

for example this

```
parent_id = PRIOR child_r_object_id
```

means "child_r_object_id from parent record is equal to parent_id of child line"

```
PRIOR parent_id = child_r_object_id
```

Means exactly the opposite - parent_id of parent record equals to child_r_object_id of a child record"

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Always bends my head this one

Comment: @smackenzie `connect by prior key = parent_key` is the standard approach for a top-down hierarchy. You could also work in the other direction (bottom up) in which case you would swap `key` and `parent_key`.

Comment: This is the same as ‘connect by parent_id = prior child_id’ I assume